# Frame rate of NSOpenGLView

Tags: macos, opengl, scenekit, nsopenglview

I have an NSOpenGLView displaying a SceneKit scene.

When using an SCNView, I could simply call showStatistics to have it display statistics such as FPS. With NSOpenGLView, is there an easy way to measure and display FPS without using the OpenGL Profiler app from Apple?